# created this python script to add 100 members but adds only 3 to 5 and stops automatically

Tags: python, python-2.x, telethon, termux

created this python script to add 100 members but adds only 3 to 5 and sometime only 1 and after that it stops automatically dont know what is the problem but maybe i think the problem is in time stamp
created this python script to add 100 members but adds only 3 to 5 and sometime only 1 and after that it stops automatically dont know what is the problem but maybe i think the problem is in time stamp

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty, InputPeerChannel, InputPeerUser, PeerUser
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PeerFloodError, UserPrivacyRestrictedError, ChatWriteForbiddenError, UserAlreadyParticipantError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest, JoinChannelRequest
from telethon import types, utils, errors
import configparser
import sys
import csv
from csv import reader
import traceback
import time
import random
from telethon.sessions import StringSession

print("                                     ")

print("                          " )

print("                                               ")

print("                                                ")


delta = 1

with open('../phone.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    list_of_rows = list(csv_reader)    
    row_number = delta
    col_number = 1
    value = list_of_rows[row_number - 1][col_number - 1]
    
with open('../api.csv', 'r') as api_obj_id:
    csv_reader = reader(api_obj_id)
    list_of_rows = list(csv_reader)
    row_number = delta
    col_number = 1
    deltaop = list_of_rows[row_number - 1][col_number - 1]
    
with open('../api.csv', 'r') as hash_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(hash_obj)
    list_of_rows = list(csv_reader)  
    row_number = delta
    col_number = 2
    deltaxd = list_of_rows[row_number - 1][col_number - 1]
    
api_id = int(deltaop)
api_hash = str(deltaxd)
pphone = value

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("../config.ini")
to_group = config['Telegram']['to_channel']


def autos():
    
    channel_username = to_group
    phone = utils.parse_phone(pphone)

    client = TelegramClient(f"../sessions/{phone}", api_id, api_hash)

    client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        print('some thing has changed')
        client.send_code_request(phone)
        client.sign_in(phone, input    ('Enter the code: '))


    input_file = '../data.csv'
    users = []
    with open(input_file, encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n")
        next(rows, None)
        for row in rows:
            user = {}
            user['srno'] = row[0]
            user['username'] = row[1]
            user['id'] = int(row[2])
        #user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
            user['name'] = row[3]
            users.append(user)

    startfrom = int(input("Start From = "))
    endto = int(input("End To = "))


    

    for user in users:
        if (int(startfrom) <= int    (user['srno'])) and (int(user['srno']) <= int(endto)):
            try:
                status = 'delta'
                if user['username'] == "":
                    print("no username, moving to next")
                    continue
            
                    
                
                client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel_username,[user['username']]))
                status = 'DONE'
                
                    #print("Waiting for 60-180 Seconds...")
                time.sleep(random.randrange(0, 5))
                
            except UserPrivacyRestrictedError:
                status = 'PrivacyRestrictedError'
                
            
            except UserAlreadyParticipantError:
                status = 'ALREADY'
                
            
            except PeerFloodError as g:
                status = 'PeerFloodError :('
                print('Script Is Stopping Now')
                time.sleep(86400)
                
            
                
            
                
            except ChatWriteForbiddenError as cwfe:
                
           
                client(JoinChannelRequest(channel_username))
                continue
                
            except errors.RPCError as e:
                status = e.__class__.__name__
        
    
            except Exception as d:
                status = d

            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
                print("Unexpected Error")
                continue
            channel_connect = client.get_entity(channel_username)
            channel_full_info = client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel=channel_connect))
            countt = int(channel_full_info.full_chat.participants_count)

            print(f"ADDING {user['name']} TO {channel_username} TOTAL: {countt} - {status}")
        elif int(user['srno']) > int(endto):
            print("Members Added Successfully!")
            stat = input('Done!\nChoose From Below:\n\n1 - Repeat The Script\nOR Just Hit Enter To Quit\n\nEnter: ')
            if stat == '1':
                autos()
            else:
                quit()
             
autos()
```

Comment: any solutions? ??